# JQuery get a contiguous sequence of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to get a contiguous array of elements using JQuery. For example for the this html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="childType2">1</div>
    <div class="childType2">2</div>
    <div class="childType2">3</div>
    <div class="childType1">4</div>
    <div class="childType1">5</div>
    <div class="childType1">6</div>
    <div class="childType1">7</div>
    <div class="childType2">8</div>
    <div class="childType1">9</div>
    <div class="childType1">10</div>
    <div class="childType1">11</div>
    <div class="childType1">12</div>
</div>
```

I want it to return the div's containing 4,5,6,7 (The first sequnce of the divs with the class="childType1").

I tried to do

```
$("<div>test</div>")($('.parent .childType2').siblings('.childType1').addBack());
```

But this of course will add the div with the text test after the last childType1  (12).

I'm not so good with JQuery.

**Edit:**

Since the div's are dynamically generated, I ended up adding for each "group" a special class post-fix of the id related to his group, and used the method described in suspectus's answer. Not exactly what i had in mind, but it works :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="childType2">1</div>
    <div class="childType2">2</div>
    <div class="childType2">3</div>
    <div class="childType1 inner">4</div>
    <div class="childType1 inner">5</div>
    <div class="childType1 inner">6</div>
    <div class="childType1 inner">7</div>
    <div class="childType2">8</div>
    <div class="childType1">9</div>
    <div class="childType1">10</div>
    <div class="childType1">11</div>
    <div class="childType1">12</div>
</div> 

 $(".inner") // gives the elements required
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `.each` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)) or `.filter` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)). If you use `.filter()` you can chain another jQuery method after it.

```
var state = 0;
var elements = [];

$('.parent div').each( function( i, elem ) {
    if( state != 2 && elem.className === "childType1" ) {
        state = 1;
        elements.push( elem );
    } else if ( state == 1 ) {
        state = 2;
    }
} );

console.log( elements );
```

Or more jQuery approach:

```
var state = 0;

$('.parent div').filter( function() {
    if( state != 2 && $(this).hasClass( "childType1" ) ) {
        state = 1;
        return true;
    } else if ( state == 1 ) {
        state = 2;
    }
    return false;
} ).css( 'background-color', 'red' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` for this :

```
var $elements = $(".childType1").filter(function() {
  var no = parseInt($(this).text(), 10) 
  return (( no > 3) && ( no < 8))
});
```

now `$elements` will contain only those matched elements between 3 and 8 ie., 4 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .each() method for looping all the divs having class="childType1"

Following is the complete code. Modify it according to your need.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $(".childType1").each(function (i) {
            if ( $(this).html() == "4" ||$(this).html() == "5" || $(this).html() == "6" ||$(this).html() == "7") {
            alert($(this).html());
            } 
        });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="childType2">1</div>
    <div class="childType2">2</div>
    <div class="childType2">3</div>
    <div class="childType1">4</div>
    <div class="childType1">5</div>
    <div class="childType1">6</div>
    <div class="childType1">7</div>
    <div class="childType2">8</div>
    <div class="childType1">9</div>
    <div class="childType1">10</div>
    <div class="childType1">11</div>
    <div class="childType1">12</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```